# How to counter BOOM! + Breaking News + 24/7 News Cycle?

Tags: android-netrunner

How a runner could counter [BOOM!](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11058) based combo ([BOOM!](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11058), [Breaking News](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01082), [24/7 News Cycle](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09019)) in the corp's deck?

[image: BOOM!] [image: Breaking News][image: 24/7 News Cycle]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need to ignore [rotation](https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2017/9/11/system-refresh/) for this, because [Breaking News](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/01082) is no longer legal as it has rotated. Here are the cards that can be used to prevent some or all of the damage from [Boom!](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11058):

- [Biometric Spoofing](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/13026) - This card is trashed to prevent 2 damage of any type, one copy brings Boom! down to 5 damage, which is survivable, multiple handle the hit even more.
- [Citadel  Sanctuary](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11070) - You trash all cards in your hand, but all the meat damage is prevented.
- [Crash Space](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/20034) - Prevents up to 3 meat damage when trashed, bringing Boom! down to 4 from one copy.
- [Guru Davinder](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/10084) - Prevents all net and meat damage, then trashes unless the runner pays 4 credits.
- [Heartbeat](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/09032) - Apex's console lets you trash installed cards per point of damage to prevent each point, any resources or programs you don't need now all are 1 point damage shields.
- [Jarogniew Mercs](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/12062) - This prevents damage by removing the counters, unlike plascrete (below) it can gain more counters when installed than the base 4 (3 + 1 for the tag it gives) based on the tags you have when you install it
- [Muresh Bodysuit](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02044) - Prevents 1 net or meat per turn, not enough to survive with a normal runner hand size but helps when combined with others here. (does not stack with itself, they all try to prevent the same single point)
- [On the Lam](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/11082) - Trashes to prevent 3 damage or avoid 3 tags. It needs to be hosted on a resource, but only On the Lam gets trashed. Note if you have tags that means the corp can get a 2 for 1 by trashing the resource you hosted On the Lam on.
- [Paparazzi](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/08087) - When you have this installed you are tagged, but can't take any meat damage. The corp likely won't play boom with this out though, they'd have to trash it first.
- [Plascrete Carapace](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/02009) - This card lets you prevent meat damage by removing counters, it gets 4 counters when installed letting you prevent 4 meat. This brings boom down to a manageable 3 damage.
- [Sacrificial Clone](https://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07050) - This pretty much resets your game, trashing all your resources and hardware and draining your credits but it prevents all damage.

Comment: There are also cards that trash to remove tags, On the Lam can work that way for instance, but this is less reliable, since they need to be used before the corp plays boom, all they do is buy you a little time, but they leave the boom in the corp hand.

Comment: On the Lam doesn't require trashing resource. It trashes itself

Comment: @Deo Definitely an odd choice for how to word it if they didn't want the resource to trash with on the lam, but yes on a re-read it does look like it works that way, edited the answer.

Comment: @Andrew yes, it is pretty weird. The only thing I can think of is that they wanted it to be affected by e.g. Same Old Thing rather than e.g. Career Fair.

Answer (score 1):

First, it should be noted that due to rotation (https://www.fantasyflightgames.com/en/news/2017/9/11/system-refresh/) this combo is no longer legal for competitive play.

For casual play, the easiest way to counter this combo is damage prevention. Plascrete Carapace (which is also rotated out of competitive play) is probably the most efficient one, but On the Lam, Jarogniew Mercs, Citadel Sanctuary among others would also work.

Apart from these direct counters, in many cases the runner might be able to stop the corp from scoring both Breaking News and a second agenda, or trash Boom! from the corps hand, since a deck running this combo probably does not have room for a lot of ice.